# ASP.NET MVC Job scheduler

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, scheduled-tasks, quartz

I'm using QUARTZ.Net as my job scheduler in my project, my goal is that i want the user to be scheduled emails and trigger them (monthly/weekly/daily).
lets say my host is on azure .. and i want to create an application and deploy it.
where should i place my scheduled, what happens if i place it under

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
      //here
    }
}
```

i want it to always run no  matter if there is a request or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can define three different jobs ( or you can trigger the same job more than once ) per day, weekly and monthly and assign the appropriate cron values to the trigger.

Use http://www.cronmaker.com/ for planning.

You can use a structure like the following.

In Global asax Application_Start method it will suffice to call QuartzServer.Start () method.

> *This code was written according to the latest version of quatz.* This is important because there is no *asynchronous* support in previous versions of **3.0**.

**EMail Job :**

> With [DisallowConcurrentExecution] attribute, it is expected to finish the current job if it comes time to trigger again when the job is running

```
   [DisallowConcurrentExecution]
    public class MailJob : IJob
    {
        public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        { 
            // Do Work
            await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("Mail Job is executing.");
        }
    }
```

**Quartz Server Class**

```
public class QuartzServer
    {

        private static IScheduler _scheduler;


        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        public static void Start()
        {
            _scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            Load();
            _scheduler.Start();
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        public static void Stop()
        {
            _scheduler.Shutdown(true);
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        private static void Load()
        {
            JobCreator.CreateJob<MailJob>(new JobInfo
            {
                JobName = "MailJob",
                TriggerName = "MainJobTrg",
                GroupName = "MainJobGroup",
                DataParamters = null,
                CronExpression = "paste here cronmaker time planning string" 
            }, ref _scheduler);   

           // Define job Daily , weekly and mounthly     
        }
}
```

**JobCreator Class**

```
 public sealed class JobCreator
    {        

        public static void CreateJob<T>(JobInfo jInfo, ref IScheduler scheduler) where T : IJob
        {
            JobBuilder jbuilder = JobBuilder.Create<T>();
            jbuilder.WithIdentity(jInfo.JobName, jInfo.GroupName);

            if (jInfo.DataParamters != null && jInfo.DataParamters.Any())
            {
                foreach (var item in jInfo.DataParamters)
                {
                    jbuilder.UsingJobData(GetDataMap(item));
                }
            }

            IJobDetail jobDetail = jbuilder.Build();

            TriggerBuilder tBuilder = TriggerBuilder.Create();
            tBuilder.WithIdentity(jInfo.TriggerName, jInfo.GroupName)
                    .StartNow()
                    .WithCronSchedule(jInfo.CronExpression);
                    //.WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                    //    .WithIntervalInSeconds(10)
                    //    .RepeatForever());

            ITrigger trigger = tBuilder.Build();

            scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
        }

        private static JobDataMap GetDataMap(DataParameter dataParameter)
        {
            JobDataMap jDataMap = new JobDataMap();

            switch (dataParameter.Value.GetType().Name)
            {
                case "Int32":
                    jDataMap.Add(dataParameter.Key, (int)dataParameter.Value);
                    break;
                case "String":
                    jDataMap.Add(dataParameter.Key, dataParameter.Value);
                    break;
            }
            return jDataMap;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

we're using Quartz.NET but not send email , we're using get data other services.We have 2 applications for this Quartz Service and Quartz Client.

**Quartz service** is a Console Application and its create job.

**Quartz Client** is a MVC application and we monitoring , jobs manually 
 trigger them.

This is the official tutorial [Quartz Tutorial](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/tutorial/index.html)